# Is a c# concurrency bag safe for websockets considering it maintains closed sockets

Tags: asp.net, websocket, asp.net-core

Most tutorials for c# asp.net websocket implementation suggest using a concurrency bag for storing the sockets. I've noticed however that the bag holds onto all the abandoned and closed web sockets. Won't this just grow and grow until it is taking up too much resources?

Here is one tutorial among others which suggest storing the socket in a concurrency bag. https://medium.com/@turowicz/websockets-in-asp-net-5-6094319a15a2#.vdoh0cute

Does anyone know if my concerns are justified in an ever increasing bag of closed sockets? Any other approaches out there that you can suggest or link to?

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using a concurrent structure is because ASP.NET uses threads when it communicates. It is a thread safe structure.

When you connect, the request is handled on a thread and then it goes through the middleware with your current request.

The concurrent structure is not the problem here. You could use a lock with a dictionary.

I would look through the structure at a periodic time (using a timer) and dispose of the sockets that are not valid anymore